# React native android app icon / splash screen issue

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

In my react native app when opening on android it briefly shows a screen that has my app icon at the center with an entirely black background then transitions to my splash/loading screen. Is there a way to either make the background entirely black on that page or instead just go straight to the splash/loading screen? Below is my res directory, styles.xml file, and splashscreen.xml file

[My res directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqsBv.png)

splashscreen.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/splashscreen_background"/>
</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/ResetEditText</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ResetEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#c8c8c8</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

I tried adding a few items to  
none of them worked

This question was already asked here but the answer was not right.

[App Icon shown before splash screen on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76396172/app-icon-shown-before-splash-screen-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Please set `windowIsTranslucent` as `true` **style.xml** file and check if it works

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.EdgeToEdge">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> // Add this line
</style>
```